# polyglossia and minted - The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!

Tags: fonts, minted, polyglossia

Trying to use `minted` with Hebrew as the default language with `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew, numerals=arabic]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}

\begin{document}
בדיקה

\begin{english}
\begin{minted}{bash}
    $ for i in {1..2}; do echo 'Hello World'; done
    Hello World
    Hello World
\end{minted}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

```
$ xelatex -shell-escape test
! Package polyglossia Error: 
The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!
Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, ]
```

I *think* I understand what the error is saying, but not sure why.

I'm in the `english` environment which should use the default English font... So why am I getting errors about Hebrew stuff?

(I did manage to workaround it by setting the default language to English, but that made other things break unfortunately)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a clear bug in how Polyglossia manages the situation, as it seems not taking into account the current language. A temporary workaround is to say

```
\let\hebrewfonttt\ttfamily
```

just after `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}` (it suffices to say it in the preamble, anyway). This assuming that you don't need Hebrew in the `minted` environment.

Comment: Thanks everybody I had similar problem for arabic font and replaced '\let\hebrewfonttt\ttfamily' by '\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily' and all works well for verbatim the english characters. but when I write arabic characters between \begin{verbatim} and \end{verbatim}, it doesn't recognize it and compiles nothing or blank line. How can I write arabic characters in verbatim ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna You need a (monospaced) font that supports Arabic. Sorry, but I can't say more without a real example. Will you make it in a new question?

Comment: I just saw your comment. I'll make a new question soon. Thanks

Comment: @ egreg. Here's the question I made.
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207636/verbatim-and-polyglossia