# Persian/Farsi polyglossia font error

Tags: fonts, polyglossia, persian

I am getting this error:

> Package polyglossia error. The current latin font PersianModern(0)
> does not contain the "Arabic" script!(polyglossia) Please define
> \arabicfont with \newfontfamily command.

I use the most up-to-date MiKTeX and Texmaker. This never used to be a problem for me, but with the new MikTeX version it seems to be a problem. I prefer not to revert back to the older v2.9.

I have read the following posts to no avail:

[polyglossia and minted - The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39262/polyglossia-and-minted-the-current-roman-font-does-not-contain-the-hebrew-scri)

[polyglossia error about file name when in draft mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266851/polyglossia-error-about-file-name-when-in-draft-mode)

[Verbatim and polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207636/verbatim-and-polyglossia)

**MWE (un-comment `%\textfarsi{را}` to get the problem)**

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{geometry}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{farsi}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfontsf[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Biolinum O}
    \newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic]{Persian Modern}
    
\begin{document}

English text  English text

%\textfarsi{را} 

English text  English text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can one find the font? Google finds many fonts when I search for “Persian Modern” — which are you trying to use?

Comment: It comes with MikTeX, which is why this is extra confusing to me. https://miktex.org/packages/persian-modern

Comment: Is Persian Modern a Unicode font, or does it use a different encoding? Amiri should work, or you can download Noto Serif Arabic, or Scheherazade by SIL.

Comment: If I substitute Amiri, I get the same problem. There seems to be a more fundamental problem going on.