# polyglossia error about file name when in draft mode

Tags: polyglossia, draft

I am using polyglossia to write a mixed language document.  The main language is Arabic, although my files are named with english script.
My latex document includes a picture:

```
\includegraphics[height=4.4in]{images/lectureoverview1.pdf}
```

Notice that the filename itself is not in Arabic script.
When I switch to draft mode using  `\documentclass[12pt,oneside,draft]{report}`
polyglossia now issues an error because the file name itself `images/lectureoverview1.pdf` is not in Arabic script.
But
What's the best way round this, since I really need Draft mode?

MWE is as follows, with the key change in the first line, whether `draft` mode or not.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,draft]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.70]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=4.4in]{images/lectureoverview1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to not having defined a monospaced font for Arabic, so the default one (Latin Modern Mono) is chosen; since it doesn't support the Arabic script, the message

```
! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Arabic script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \arabicfont with \newfontfamily.
```

is issued. It's a well known problem with Polyglossia that such a message refers to `\arabicfont` and not to `\arabicfonttt` (the same happens for the sans serif case). See [polyglossia and minted - The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39262/polyglossia-and-minted-the-current-roman-font-does-not-contain-the-hebrew-scri)

The problem is solved by defining `\arabicfonttt`:

```
\documentclass[
  draft
]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.70]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}

\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt{Latin Modern Mono} % maybe one that supports Arabic
% or define \setmonofont to one that supports arabic
% \setmonofont{...}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=4.4in]{duck}
\end{document}
```

Here I use again Latin Modern Mono; of course this won't do if you need Arabic in monospaced text.

Comment: Extra explanation helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be enough to use `\textenglish` but `\ttfamily` used to set the filename seems to want to switch back, so this just locally disables it, setting the filename in Roman.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,draft]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.70]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

\textenglish{%
\def\ttfamily\relax
\includegraphics[height=4.4in]{example-image}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is more complicated than the answer below, and requires more changes

Answer (score 2):

You can define yourself a key to switch the ttfont (I have no idea why graphicx expects `\\` at the end):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,draft]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.70]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{ttenglish}[]{\let\ttfamily\ttfamilylatin\\}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\includegraphics[height=4.4in,ttenglish]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

You could also set \ttfamily to some font which has the script:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,draft]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.70]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}

\newfontfamily\ttfamily[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.70]{DejaVu Sans Mono}% 
\begin{document}


\includegraphics[height=4.4in]{example-image}

\end{document}
```